# Creating complex objects in REST

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have been mostly doing server side rendering apps and now I am starting to do WebApi + javascript framework for client side rendering.

I have the sitation where form for creating `User` also has fields for `Organization` which will be created along with `User` in one transaction. If I would do server side rendering I would make `CreateUserViewModel` which has all fields from form, my controller action would take that `CreateUserViewModel`, and then map `CreateUserViewModel`  fields to `User` and `Organization` entities fields.

But if I am making REST api, should I also have this kind of logic with ViewModel which contains all fields from form, and which is the parameter of action method in controller? Or I should have two separate methods `POST: /users` i `POST: /organizations` and at client side do the mapping from input fields to `User` and `Organization` and call those two methods separately? If second option is the correct way, how would I make it transactional then?

Comment: "If second option is the correct way, how would I make it transactional then?" - surely if it needs to be transactional, the second option is not the correct way.  But you might consider whether it needs to be transactional.  Without more detail it's difficult to tell, but one might expect a user to be a member of an organization, so perhaps the organization could be created first without using a transaction.

Comment: It has to be transactional, User must enter Organization details when registering, one cannot exist without another. Not my specification, it is how client wants.

Comment: @Alexsa, you seem to be implying that Organization details are essentially attributes of the user in your data model (i.e. you don't have >1 user with the same Organization).  In which case, your second option of separate calls for User and Organization is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

its far better to separate your actions in controller and send two separated view model to them , then you can do the Crud in business layer as transaction  or you can use unit of work pattern if you are using entity framework.
consider in some other forms you want to add just user , then you have to send a big view model with a lot of empty fields if you chose first approach. 
BR MReza